# How to snap the tkinter canvas to the top left of the screen?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I have made a window that resizes to the users screen resolution, but this window(tkinter) doesnt snap to the top left corner when it opens this can be a problem when trying to get the sizes and positions right when coding.

Is there any way I can fix it?

Also the line im using to get the Y axis screensize 
`root.winfo_screenheight()`
doesn't like to take into account the toolbar and so goes under it.

Is there any way i can get the program to actively take into account the toolbar?

Comment: Briefly: there's a fullscreen option.

Comment: Is that the full screen button you have to click in the top right or a line of code?

Comment: It's described in detail in the linked question above.